# How do I get my scrapy spider to extract data from multiple pages by clicking "next" button?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape GTA V vehicle information from gtabase.com using a scrapy spider. Here's what I'm trying to achieve -

1. Use `"https://www.gtabase.com/grand-theft-auto-v/vehicles/#sort=attr.ct3.frontend_value&sortdir=desc&page=1"` as my `start_urls`
2. Get the link to all vehicles on the page
3. Go to each link (from #2) and get the vehicle `name` and `manufacturer`
4. Click on the next page xpath (if available. I guess this should happen from the `start_urls`) and repeat #2 and #3.

I understanding there are other ways to loop through the pages, however I want to learn how to use this method by clicking on a "next" button if available.

In the code below, I'm also trying to test out the spider by only extracting the information (see #3 above) from the first 4 links and for the first 3 pages (see #4 above). However I am only getting the information for the first 4 links on the first page. There appears to be something wrong with my code where the spider is not able to go to the next page, and I can't figure out the issue. Notice in the code I am using `itertools` to get only the first 4 links and using a `counter` to loop through the first 2 pages. Can anyone help me debug -

**Spider Code -**

```
# Packages        
import scrapy
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as WDW
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains as AC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import itertools
import time


# Spider Method
class VehiclesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "vehicles"
    allowed_domains = ["gtabase.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.gtabase.com/grand-theft-auto-v/vehicles/#sort=attr.ct3.frontend_value&sortdir=desc&page=1"]
    
    # Initialize Counter
    # counter = 0

     # Driver Init
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = chrome_options)
        
        
     # Parse Method (Get Links)
    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        
        # Scroll Till The Middle of the Page
        viewport_height = self.driver.execute_script("return Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);")
        self.driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {viewport_height/2});")
        
        # Store Response
        resp = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        
        # Extract Links
        for i, vehicle_card in itertools.islice(enumerate(resp.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'product') and contains(@class, 'item') and contains(@class, 'ln-element')]")), 4): # Testing With 4 Links       
            link = response.urljoin(vehicle_card.xpath(".//a[contains(@class, 'product') and contains(@class, 'item-link')]/@href").get())
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback = self.parse_details)
             
    # Extract Vehicle Details
    def parse_details(self, response):
        
        # Open URL
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        
        # Extract Data
        for vehicle_info in response.xpath("//div[@class='article-content']"):
            name = response.xpath(".//h2[5]/text()").get(default = "NA").strip()
            manufacturer = response.xpath(".//dl/dd//span//a[contains(@title, 'Vehicle Class')]/text()").get(default = "NA").strip()
        
            yield {
                "name": name
                , "manufacturer": manufacturer
            }            
            
            
            # Increment Counter / Check if Counter is <= 3
            self.counter += 1
            if self.counter < 4:

            # Get Next Page URL & Callback parse_details
                next_page = response.xpath("(//a[@title='Next'])[2]/@href").get()
                if next_page:
                    absolute_url = f"https://www.gtabase.com/grand-theft-auto-v/vehicles/{next_page}"
                    yield SeleniumRequest(
                        url = absolute_url,
                        wait_time = 5,
                        callback = self.parse_details
                    )
                else:
                    self.log("REACHED PAGE LIMIT, SPIDER STOPPED")
        
    # Close Spider    
    def spider_closed(self, reason):
        self.driver.quit()
```

I also have the following settings in my `settings.py` file -

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = "chrome"
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = ChromeDriverManager().install()
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['-headless']  # '--headless' if using chrome instead of firefox
```